# StreamReader.CurrentEncoding different when run through chocolatey or octopus

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, octopus-deploy, chocolatey

I've got an azure VM with a number of files on it. Some of these files are pretty messed up, for example, containing a UTF8 BOM and non-UTF8 characters, in particular, smart quotes like so:

```
<option ef="“Late”" />
```

In order to fix this, I have a small C# utility that opens a `StreamReader` on each:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.ASCII, true);
```

calls `.ReadToEnd()`, and then checks `CurrentEncoding`. If I run this process in a powershell window, it returns `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding` as expected because of the smart quotes and because that's what it does when run anywhere else. If I run it inside a chocolatey package or through octopus deploy, `CurrentEncoding` equals `System.Text.UTF8Encoding`.

I'm calling `.ReadToEnd()` because [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.currentencoding(v=vs.113).aspx) says that performing a read will set the encoding correctly. What is different about chocolatey and octopus that is making `StreamReader` guess the wrong encoding?

Comment: what do yo mean by saying "accurate" ? Encoding is variable by its means.

Comment: What makes you think that's not accurate? If chocolatey changes the encoding to UTF8 then your process will be launch as UTF8.

Comment: @Tigran I know these files are ASCII because everywhere this is run except through my new chocolatey package, it detects them as ASCII and converts them to UTF8.

Comment: @Gusman Please see my comment above and also my post update.

Comment: As long as a file has no BOM there is no implicit encoding, the raw data can be interpreted differently.

Comment: Just a note, it says "The value can be different after the first call to any Read method", that doesn't means it will always set the correct encoding, if the file has a BOM or any other tag to identify the encoding, then the stream will change it.

Comment: @LotPings It still seems like the same code, run against the same file, should produce the same result even if it could plausibly be interpreted differently under different circumstances.

Comment: @Gusman You are correct but it would appear, since I'm specifying ASCII at the time of instantiation, that running under chocolatey is actually producing an incorrect change to UTF8.

Comment: Maybe if you post all the info at once instead of small pieces on edits we could see the full picture...

Comment: @Gusman Sorry. Let me know if I can post anything else.

Comment: @sirdank We are going to need a lot more context here - plus this looks like a bug - best to log it at https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues so that we can triage it better and prioritize it. HTH

Comment: @ferventcoder QA said it happens through chocolatey as well as octopus deploy so I'm no longer sure it's related to chocolatey. I can still submit this as a bug if you think I ought to.

Comment: It couldn't hurt - best that we are aware it is occurring.